# Svnsync can't sync repository

Tags: svn, svnsync

I have a read access to remote Subversion repository and i want to clone it via svnsync. The synchronization starts ok and progress well, but near the end i get error that looks like:

```
Transmitting file data ...svnsync: File not found: transaction '12893-qyy', path
 '/project_name/trunk/path/to/file.cpp'
```

I can sucessfully check out the revision in question, previous revision and next revision. All files are in place. I have checked log for file in question - it's folder is moved into this place in previous revision.

Is it any way i can force svnsync to ignore this error and continue sync? I don't have admin access to repository so i can't fix it.

UPDATED: Answering comments: i have checked same subversion client as server use (1.6.6), latest stable (1.6.17) and beta version (1.7). All gives exactly same error. Also, i can successfully checkout 'broken' repository: latest revision, revision in question (12893), revision before it (12892) and revision after it (12894) without any errors.

UPDATED: Answering more comments: svn log shows that in revision 12892 folder 'to' was moved from `/repo/other_project/trunk/source_path` into `/repo/project_name/trunk/path`

Comment: Are you running the same version of SVN that the server is?

Comment: Yes. I have tried exact same version, latest stable 1.6.17 version and 1.7 beta version. Same error.

Comment: Weird. Have you tried a checkout to see if that works? If the repo is broken, you wont be able to sync.

Comment: @qor72 Sure thing. I can checkout latest revision, the revision 12893, revision before it and revision after it :(. All i need to do is to sync repository - i don't care if it will contain file in question or not. But svnsync simply stops on this stupid error and gives me no options to continue sync :(.

Comment: Given that it's trying to make a copy (sync) of the repo, it's not too surprising - if it hits an error, and skips over a file, it wont be able to apply revisions to that file going forward. Painful in this instance...

Comment: Did you have a folder with the same name in previous revisions? Also, can be the same issue as http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2010-07/0055.shtml (sorry if you've already googled that)

Comment: @pmod It may be the specified issue. From a mailing list archive it's unclear is it fixed or not :(.

Comment: I know that svnsync requires rev-prop change hook access, or it will fail. Do you have that? I'm just shooting in the dark here. It sounds like you know what you're doing and you've googled and tried everything else.

Comment: @David Sure thing. svnsync will not start syncing if target repository don't have this hook, so all is set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you can checkout revisions before and after this I would guess that you do not have any repository corruption.  svnsync works by "replaying" transactions as opposed to mirroring data or something like that.  As such, there can be bugs that prevent it from replaying a transaction.  I would guess something about that commit has triggered a bug.  You can run svn log -c 12893 -v to look at the revision in more detail.  I would guess it has something in it like a 'R'eplace that is causing the problem.  You could gather info and send it to users@subversion.apache.org so that it could be analyzed and hopefully fixed.

Here are some other ideas:

- How is the source repository accessed?  file:// http:// etc.  If it is http:// you could try changing from using the default HTTP library of Neon to Serf and see if it still has the problem.  You can do that by adding --config-option=servers:global:http-library=serf to the svnsync command when you run it.  It is worth a try.
- See if you can dump the revision.  svnadmin dump -r12892:12893 --incremental reposname > dumpfile
- If you can dump the revision, then load you can manually load it into the target repository using svnadmin load.
- If you can load the revision, then you can manually fix the properties for svnsync so that it know it did that revision.  svn ps --revprop -r0 svn:sync-last-merged-rev 123893 url://to/mirror

UPDATED: The problem was solved by using new `svnrdump` utility from subversion 1.7 RC2.

Comment: Repository is accessed via HTTPS. I can't change access method since i don't have admin access to repository. I can't dump revision since i don't have admin access to repository.

Comment: svn log shows that in revision 12892 folder 'to' was moved from `/repo/other_project/trunk/source_path` into `/repo/project_name/trunk/path`

Comment: You can change the library svnsync uses when it reads from the https repository.  By default it uses neon, but there is another library serf that works a little different.  *Maybe* it does not have same problem.

Comment: Since you appear willing to try the 1.7 RC, it also comes with a new tool named svnrdump that lets you do dump over http.  Try this:  svnrdump dump --incremental -r12892:12893 https://server/repos > dumpfile

Comment: svnrdump works without errors and dumps entire repository. After that how can i re-create repository from dumpfile?

Comment: Sorry, I do not get notified of comments for some reason need to check my settings.  You can use svnadmin load to load the dumpfile.  And if you use the svnsync from 1.7 to --init your repository you can have it set the last synched revision to the revisions you loaded via the dump file.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the responses above, the last resort that fixed my issue was to use the svndumpfilter command to exclude the nodes that were corrupt.

Each time I tried to load the specific revision after using svnrdump, I was getting the following error;

...
svnadmin: E160004: Filesystem is corrupt
svnadmin: E200014: Checksum mismatch while reading representation:
   expected:  77ec72e82afddd1cb8d2c63760cf4dbb
     actual:  f34fb5883dffffec3cd59a69f8a2cb99

If you have created the dump of the revision as rev12892.dmp, then you can exclude a path, eg. "/project_name/trunk/path" as follows;

> svndumpfilter exclude /project_name/trunk/path < rev12892.dmp > pruned_dump_file

See the svn redbook for details about the svndumpfilter command : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.commands.c.exclude.html